# Nonsense date coming from year and month function

Tags: stata

I have a `birthtime` variable:

```
birthtime 
1976m2
1979m8
```

I ran the following:

```
gen birthyear=year(birthtime)
gen birthmonth=month(birthtime)
```

However, the result is nonsense.

Do the `year` and `month` functions not work for this format?

How can I retrieve year and month from the `birthtime` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to study Stata's [SIF-to-SIF conversions](https://www.stata.com/manuals/ddatetime.pdf#ddatetimeSyntaxSIF-to-SIFconversion):

```
clear

input birthtime
403
404
405
406
407
end

generate birthyear = year(dofm(birthtime))
generate birthmonth = month(dofm(birthtime))

list, abbreviate(10)

     +------------------------------------+
     | birthtime   birthyear   birthmonth |
     |------------------------------------|
  1. |       403        1993            8 |
  2. |       404        1993            9 |
  3. |       405        1993           10 |
  4. |       406        1993           11 |
  5. |       407        1993           12 |
     +------------------------------------+
```

Also:

```
format %tm birthtime

list, abbreviate(10)

     +------------------------------------+
     | birthtime   birthyear   birthmonth |
     |------------------------------------|
  1. |    1993m8        1993            8 |
  2. |    1993m9        1993            9 |
  3. |   1993m10        1993           10 |
  4. |   1993m11        1993           11 |
  5. |   1993m12        1993           12 |
     +------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following does the job.

```
gen int temp = dofm(birthtime)
gen int birthyear = year(temp)
gen byte birthmonth = month(temp)
```

The result is

```
birthyear birthmonth
1976         2
1979         8
```